# Post data from iPhone to ASP.NET

Tags: iphone, ios

I succesfully tested this code but it works only for PHP, and if I put there name of TextBox from ASP, it doesnt work. I would be greatful for any help with it for ASP.NET

```
    if (![nameInput.text isEqual: @""] && ![passInput.text isEqual: @""])
{
    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name0=%@&name1=%@", nameInput.text, passInput.text];
    NSData *data = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ucimsewebu.eu/info.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];

    [webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

And Here is ASP TextBox Codes

```
 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span id="cphmain_LabelJmeno">Přihlašovací jméno:</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="ctl00$cphmain$TextBoxjmeno" type="text" id="cphmain_TextBoxjmeno" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span id="cphmain_LabelHeslo">Heslo:</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="ctl00$cphmain$TextBoxHeslo" type="password" id="cphmain_TextBoxHeslo" title="heslo" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
```

Comment: Refer to this: http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/connecting-the-iphone-with-aspnet-web-pages

Comment: I dont have any I just tryied to use this, and without name0 used name of ASP'S TextBox name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the request collection

```
For Each Item In Request.Form
 Response.Write Item & ": " & Request.Form(Item) & "<br>"
Next
```